# Laravel 4 query running

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a table in my db called 'players'. There is a column 'experience' in that table. I want to fetch which is the highest experience, and to display a players name (column 'name'in 'players').

Let's say:

1. Lokoko 136 exp
2. Hihon 132 exp
3. ...

I've thought about something like this, but couldn't get any further..

```
$players = Player::where('experience')->get();

foreach ($players as $player)
{
    //
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$players = Player::orderBy('experience','desc')->get();

foreach ($players as $player)
{
    //
}
```

Comment: it works, how could I display the name and the experience? something like: `@foreach ($players as $player)

    {{ $player->name }}
    {{ $player->experience }}


@endforeach` ?:P